# What is the difference between ActionSupport and DefaultActionSupport?

Tags: java, struts2

What is `DefaultActionSupport` class in Struts2 and why do I use it when I am using `ActionSupport`? Is there any necessity of using `DefaultActionSupport` instead of `ActionSupport`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use [`DefaultActionSupport`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/DefaultActionSupport.html).

> A simple action support class that sets properties to be able to serve.

Properties:

- `successResultValue`: never used

There's no necessity to use this class instead of `ActionSupport`.

Comment: I don't use it, do you?

Comment: Ok, if you find any, let me know.

Comment: @tanmoy Did you find any? If not there's no usage available.